# Reading data from D+ and D- pins of a USB

Tags: sensors

So I have this optical mouse with me, which has a PAN3504DL-TJ optical sensor. It has a USB interface and when I looked up the internet, all I could find was tutorials using A2501 or sensors in those lines and it has pins like SCLK and SDI but I don't have them instead I have D+ and D-. I understand that these are the data pins so what I did was take two wires and plug them into my Analog Pins of my dsPIC30F4011 and read data from it. After setting up UART communication and transmitting data, all I get are numbers running continuously.

[image: Screenshot of Termite receiving information from the Analog Pins which are connected to the D+ and D- of the Optical Sensor]

What I want to do is to read coordinates over the analog pins as the mouse aka the sensor moves on a surface. I would use this for position control for my robot.
So my question is how do I read coordinates from the Optical Sensor over the D+ and D- lines through my Analog Pins ?

Comment: Sounds like you need to plug it in to a USB port.  Does your microcontroller support USB?  If it's designed for USB you're not going to get anywhere connecting it to anything but USB.  Do you have a datasheet?

Comment: Yeah I power my Microcontroller via USB cable and also read other sensory information through the same USB interface otherwise called UART. By datasheet you mean the microcontroller's or the optical sensor's ?

Answer (score 1):

The mouse is sending data using the USB protocol.  You will have to read and decode that protocol to get the mouse data.

Comment: I have found that trying to decipher the HID (human interface device) protocol is a huge headache.  (at least on linux).  However, you might be able to hack your mouse and access the communications to/from the chip that actually does the optical differencing which you want.  i.e. cut out the USB interface.

Answer (score 1):

Use different PAN, PAN3101 in praticular. How to do that? See this (chapter "5.3.6 PAN3101") https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/2733/2663

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, you'll need to implement the protocol for communication (most likely HID). I recommend you buy an optical mouse with PS/2 protocol because it will be much much easier to implement, there are even numerous solutions for it online (as in codes and libraries).

Regards