# How to implement a distance proximity sensor with wider range

Tags: sensors

More in the line of robotics observing their environment, I'm trying to implement a proximity sensor that can sense objects in front of it to a least up to $-30^ \circ \space$ to   $\space+30^ \circ $ of it's direction of propagation.

There are only two ways I can think of

1. Multiple Infrareds.     Con: more spacious
2. Fast-Motor.  Con: expensive in money and time-complexity wise

I'm currently using a [Proximity Sensor with up to 10ft distance capability](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Infrared/gp2y0a02yk_e.pdf)

Comment: Probably overkill: Vision. Other option, use ultrasonic sensor(s).

Comment: -30 to +30 degrees is not really a good measure. At what distance do you wish for that? Most sensors have polar plots in their datasheets that describe their sensitivity.

Comment: I need 5ft atleast

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out these ultrasonic proximity sensors for example: http://www.maxbotix.com/pictures/HRUSB-MaxSonar-EZ/HRUSB-MaxSonar-EZ%20Beam%20Patterns.gif
And then use two or three of them if needed to get a wider field.
They can be bought all over, sparkfun being one of the shops.

Regards

Comment: Be careful about interference between separate sensors.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the purpose, but −30∘ to +30∘ (cone shaped beam) smells like ultrasonic sensors.

However, if you don't like ultrasonic and you are more "infrared person" you may also make your own scanner (SHARP GP2Y0A21YK0F + RC servo) like here (chapter "5.3.3 Skaner 2D"):
http://www.forbot.pl/forum/download.php?id=676&sid=54f9ba7ac5b724b64bfff3686de0e39c
http://www.forbot.pl/forum/topics20/fuzja-sygnalow-sensorycznych-dla-robotow-minisumo-vt2151.htm

Comment: Please, indicate that the first link is in Polish and surely not everybody can read it

Comment: @SnakeSanders use translate.google.com